# Import Neo4j CSV into OrientDB

Tags: export-to-csv, graph-databases, orientdb, orientdb3.0

How do you import a [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/) CSV Database Dump into [OrientDB](http://orientdb.org/)? 
Because I'm not sure what this error is pointing to. 
I've since switched from Neo4j-Dump conversion into direct CSV.

Reproduction Steps:

1. Imported [NIH-Lung-Cancer Graph-Database CSV-Data](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/RIXLG8)
2. Created an [OrientDB-Docker-container](https://hub.docker.com/_/orientdb)
3. Ran the oetl.sh [file/path/for/config.json](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/etl/ETL-Introduction.html)

I expected to see the command work like show in the documentation. 
Running the shell command:

```
oetl.sh /home/dataverse_files/input/Orientdb/Anatomy-config.json
```

Log response:

```
OrientDB etl v.3.2.17 (build 211ebdf4e697bc32a41a4456f09b4c47f2a4eb4b, branch UNKNOWN) https://www.orientdb.com 

XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX:XXX INFO  Detected limit of amount of simultaneously open files is 1048576,  limit of open files for disk cache will be set to 523776 [ONative]create contextremote:localhost:2480
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Error on creating ETL processor
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.parse(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:172)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.parseConfigAndParametersWithContext(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:103)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.parseConfigAndParameters(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:68)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.main(OETLProcessor.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1927)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.loader.OETLOrientDBLoader.getDatabasePool(OETLOrientDBLoader.java:471)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.loader.OETLOrientDBLoader.configure(OETLOrientDBLoader.java:409)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.configureComponent(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:179)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.configureLoader(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:218)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.parse(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:143)
        ... 3 more
```

The `Anatomy-config.json` looks like

```json
{
    "config": { "log": "debug" },
    "begin": [],
    "source": {
        "file": {
            "path": "/home/dataverse_files/input/Anatomy.csv",
            "lock": true
        }
    },
    "extractor": { "row": {} },
    "transformers": [
        {
            "csv": {
                "separator": ",",
                "nullValue": "NULL",
                "skipFrom": 1,
                "skipTo": 1
            }
        },
        { "vertex": { "class": "V" } }
    ],
    "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "remote:localhost:2480",
            "dbUser": "root",
            "dbPassword": "rootpwd",
            "dbAutoCreate": true,
            "tx": false,
            "batchCommit": 1000,
            "dbType": "graph"
        }
    }
}
```

<s>I [imported / restored a Neo4j-Database-Dump](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/restore-backup/) 

From a [NIH Lung-Cancer Graph-Database](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8842806/) found on [Havard-Dataverse Dataset](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/RIXLG8). 

[Exported a CSV from a Neo4j Database](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/export/csv/). 

Created an [OrientDB-Docker-container](https://hub.docker.com/_/orientdb) 

And ran the oetl.sh [file/path/for/config.json](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/etl/ETL-Introduction.html).</s>

Comment: See the comments for a [related orientdb issue](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/7109).

Comment: I've already read this and tried editing my configuration files and I'm still getting errors.

Comment: Yes, I've also seen this video https://youtu.be/uMpb7aRzVM4?t=4810

Comment: You have edited your question and now it is actually a completely different question. In general, you should create a new question instead of changing an existing question too much. Otherwise it is impossible to follow any comments and/or answers to the original question (and nobody else can benefit from them), and your edited question is polluted with inapplicable comments/answers

Comment: It's the same question but without the database dump conversion. Still asking about the CSV.